# What privileges should I grant to my InnoDB MySQL user?

Tags: mysql, innodb, privileges, sql-grant

I've a MySQL user (InnoDB engine) and I was wondering what would be the safe privileges to grant for it?
Currently I've granted it permission to access the specific database and these privileges:

```
SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES
```

But since it's InnoDB I was wondering if I need to explicitly grant LOCK TABLES privilege to this user? Also I'm not sure whether I even need to grant CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES for it.
Could you help me out here to figure out which privileges should I grant?
Hibernate will have access to this user so I was also wondering what would be enough for it to work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should grant the **minimum** privileges the users needs in order to use the system.

For testing by all means use a `grant all on the database`.

**Lock things down come production time**
But in production you should only grant `select` on the tables.
Grant `insert` and `update` **only** on tables the user actually needs to add or alter data in.
`Create` is a privilege that users almost never need. *(unless you want them to design the database for you :-)*.
Ditto for `index`, `alter`, you don't want your users to wield that power.
`create temp tables`  may be OK, *IF* your app creates temp tables.

Comment: It isn't a good idea to grant table-level privileges if you care about performance. MySQL will have to check them for every single query, unlike database level privileges which are usually checked only once per session.